# Возвращение return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TTAppDelegate class]));

Tags: xcode

Только учусь работать в xcode, возникла проблема: Когда через симулятор нажимаю на кнопку, которая должна перекидывать в другую вьюшку, то возвращает в xcode, в `Thread 1` и зеленым цветов выделяется строчка ...

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
                         NSStringFromClass([TTAppDelegate class]));
```

Помогите пожалуйста, буду признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Это значит, что приложение упало. Посмотрите в логи, чтобы попробовать понять, что идет не так. Скорее всего по нажатию на кнопку отрабатывает какой-то проблемный код и все крэшится